# Why am I banned from answering on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, answers, post-ban

I tried to answer a question but apparently I am banned. I only have one question and no answers, so I don't think that it makes sense. If it does, then why?

Comment: The ban takes _deleted_ answers into account too.

Comment: I'm seeing two questions (at 0 and at -1). No idea how many deleted questions and answers, which count as well.

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/1983495) and share with us.

Comment: I think it's unfair to downvote this user's question.  They ask a really good question, and at this point, they've fallen into a non-obvious trap. It's not fair to penalize them for asking why.

Comment: @Oded: Does the system still have bans? I thought it's using rate-limiting from now on.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It seems pretty clear that they didn't even read the directions they're linked to when trying to post.  He knows that he  doesn't have zero answers, and he knows that deleted posts count, if he read the linked page.

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion They changed nothing about the bans (to my knowledge), they just added rate limiting in addition to the bans.  The rate limiting also makes it harder to get banned, because people are often prevented from posting the posts that would get them banned.

Comment: @servy He doesn't know that because the answers are so old they don't show up any more; and I have to say that unless I look at my profile page, I don't even know what I've answered in the past week, so it'd be disingenuous to expect this user to remember what they posted months ago.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker You wouldn't remember exactly what you've posted in each answer last week *because you've posted too many of them to remember*.  But you'd probably remember if you've ever posted one at all.

Comment: @Servy I posted a question a few years ago, before I started regularly using the site, I managed to achieve the Tumbleweed badge and it has since been deleted - I have no idea what that question was, if it got any downvotes or what. Since then I've actually read the help text, lurked more, and as a result, don't really ask questions. It happens - not often, but it does.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker It would be insincere to expect this user to remember their old posts?  I'm not sure I follow your meaning here.  Is there another sense of 'disingenuous' that would apply?

Comment: *"They ask a really good question"* - Someone is a member for over an year, got an answer ban for posting questions as answers., and asks about the ban in *stackoverflow*. That is kind of repeating his mistakes. At least by that time he should've went through the **help** section. **Really** not good.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You have three old answers that are deleted:

- [Opening a virtual serial port created by socate with qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867628/opening-a-virtual-serial-port-created-by-socat-with-qt/24492287#24492287)
- [C - Why is const cast evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10498292/c-why-is-const-cast-evil/21082964#21082964)
- [Libsub - Basic example wanted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813764/libusb-basic-example-wanted/14357606#14357606)

In two cases, you were asking a new question as an answer.

That's wrong, and that's why those answers were deleted.

In the [third case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813764/libusb-basic-example-wanted/14357606#14357606), it appears you're commenting on the question in an answer box; also verboten.

It sucks that you made three mistakes and were banned, that's for sure -- but they were over such a period of time that the system believes you didn't learn from your mistake (most likely).

Since we only show recent deleted answers to users, there would have been no way for you to know your previous answers were deleted unless you visited the site, clicked your 'Answers' page, and looked at 'recent deleted answers' in the timeframe those answers were still visible in that page.

So all around, the communication could have been better.

I'll see if we can get those answers disassociated from your account, because you really did fall into a trap that would be hard to get out of and hard to realize you're even in.

In the future, please don't treat Stack Overflow like a traditional forum: "Questions" go into the "Ask Question" box, "Answers" go into the box that says "Add an Answer".

[Previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170487/16587).

Comment: Three answers will trigger a postban? Wow..

Comment: what's so "*wow*" about it Joe? That's actually great!

Comment: @Joe It's more complicated than just that, actually. (I'm not talking specifics about this user, which I have not seen; just generally)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I've updated my post with more information; just wanted to get that initial information out there.

Comment: @Joe Maybe the nature of the answers also counts? It's one thing to post technically bad answers. It's another thing to post answers that show the user is not paying attention to the instructions regarding to what can be posted in answers, which appears to be the case here.

Comment: Excellent, and I agree about this not being obvious.

Comment: @vba4all I didn't say it was a bad thing, nor necessarily a good thing - these kind of heuristics will never be perfect, and as the post now reflects, there is a little more to it than just three posts.

Comment: No. The system works as expected and yeah call it a trap if you want... but blame only yourself if you fall in it. One hasn't read the rules therefore they should be disallowed to post further "answers" - increasing the load of moderation work etc. That's exactly what should have happened. Someone has spent a good amount of time putting a help-centre together for a reason.

Comment: @vba4all Due to the circumstances (visiting non-regularly, posting answers that are very far apart, and not seeing the ban until now (when all of the deleted recent answers wouldn't show up any more)), this is a trap the user fell into. There's no feedback when an answer is deleted, so they wouldn't have known they were doing something bad.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Auto-generated comments posted from the LQP queue result in notifications to the user persisting even when the post is deleted (unlike normal comments) which was the case for at least one of this user's answers.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I completely understand the circumstances. So what if every other person visiting the site becomes a non-regular typing questions into answers? IMO, The system **does** work as expected. People who don't pay attention on multiple occasions ([notifications](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277004/why-am-i-banned-from-answering-in-stackoverflow#comment118346_277005)) should be penalised.

Comment: @vba4all The ban part is expected; the fact that a non-regular user wouldn't be able to see why they were banned (because all evidence is gone) is not expected and that's what has generated the support request. I agree with the OP that this is a trap that's not hard to fall into.  I don't agree in all cases; but this specific set of circumstances would make it hard for anyone to realize what was happening, and even harder to fix.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Ok, if there really is no evidence (and hasn't been on each login) I agree the user would have not known why. Although,  I think they should have seen notifications on the comments posted below their answers, even if they are deleted as they were the owner - and the owner can see their own deleted posts.

Comment: I really did not remember that, I'am sorry, my mistake was that I did not read how to post so I guess I deserve the ban.

Comment: How many other users have been hit in the same way?   I think if an user's answer has been deleted they should be told as part of the process of them posting their next answer.

Comment: @IanRingrose That's a really good point. That should be a feature request.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker, first do a database search to how many user have an answer ban from answers that are posted more then a few days apart...

Comment: @IanRingrose I don't have access to that information through the database; I don't have access to the database. I don't think the data dump exposes users who are banned either.

Comment: Maybe this is another argument for users being allowed to see all of their own deleted posts on their own user page.

Comment: @Zack [Absolutely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170487/16587).

Comment: I've been hit in the same way, and it's a horrible trap to fall into. I had a deleted downvoted question and some user decided to downvote one of my upvoted questions, which pushed me into the trap- similar story here. ***Mostly we just learn our lesson and have to contribute to the site (mostly answering questions).***

Comment: your "Absolutely" and "Previously" just cost me 50 MSE repz to bounty that request

Comment: They are told, @Ian. Not sure anyone listens, but if you're new and your last answer was deleted, you get warned when you go to post another one.

Comment: @Shog9 Not just when you're new, it always happens if you will be question-banned if you delete the question. When you're question-banned and delete a question it'll also warn with something similar to `warning: Removing this question will not get you out of your question-ban`.

Comment: yeah, there are a lot more warnings for questions, @cybermonkey

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I skipped few comments, but I think you forgot to tell him that "Questions about programming should go into stackoverflow and questions about stackoverflow should go into meta-stackoverflow."

Comment: Yet another reason for *showing users their own deleted content*, not just for a little while, perhaps on a tab of its own.